# Including a Validator class from a Concern in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I've got a custom `EachValidator` that is used in two different models. I moved it to a Concern to DRY the models:

```rb
module Isbn
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class IsbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
      GOOD_ISBN = /^97[89]/.freeze

      def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
       # snip...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  include Isbn

  validates :isbn, allow_nil: true, isbn: true
end
```

```rb
class BookPart < ApplicationRecord
  include Isbn

  validates :isbn, allow_nil: true, isbn: true
end
```

When running Rails (in this case via RSpec), I get this warning:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
C:/Users/USER/api/app/models/concerns/isbn.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Isbn::IsbnValidator::GOOD_ISBN
C:/Users/USER/api/app/models/concerns/isbn.rb:16: warning: previous definition of GOOD_ISBN was here
```

Is there any way to avoid it and include the validator cleanly in each model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you include your `Isbn` module it triggers `included` method which opens `IsbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator` class and creates `GOOD_ISBN` constant and `validate_each` method inside of it. Note that these constant and method are created each time in the same class - `IsbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator`.

So, the first time you included `Isbn` module you created `GOOD_ISBN` constant inside `IsbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator`, after that you included `Isbn` module into another class and `included` method tried to create `GOOD_ISBN` constant again in `IsbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator` and obviously failed with that error you got.

So instead your `included` method should look like this:

```rb
module Isbn
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    GOOD_ISBN = /^97[89]/.freeze

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
     # snip...
    end
  end
end
```

This way `GOOD_ISBN` and `validate_each` will be created for the classes you import `Isbn` into (i.e. for `Book` and `BookPart`)